# Start child activity on parent's Activity Source

Tags: c#, distributed-tracing

Please see the following contrived code:

```cs
public class Child
{
    public void DoChild()
    {
        using Activity? activity = Activity.Current?.Source.StartActivity();
        activity?.SetTag(AnotherTag, AnotherValue);
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    private Child _child;

    public void DoParent()
    {
        Activity.Current?.SetTag(TheTag, TheValue);
        _child.DoChild();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to start a child activity and write an activity tag.

For this, is it safe/not an anti-pattern to call `Activity.Current?.Source.StartActivity()`? Or do I have to instantiate my own `ActivitySource` as described [in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs#activitysource) like this?

```cs
public class Child
{
    private static ActivitySource source = new ActivitySource("Child", "1.0.0");

    public void DoChild()
    {
        using Activity? activity = source.StartActivity();
        activity?.SetTag(AnotherTag, AnotherValue);
    }
}
```

Thx!

Comment: I'd prefer the second the solution to avoid issues if the activity itself is null but both solutions are valid. IMO always go with what the doc says if u are unsure